# VBA: counting the number of columns within a range until encountering a specified value

Tags: vba, excel

What I'd like to achieve through VBA is to count the number of columns within a certain range, but in such a manner that the counting would stop once a specified cell value is encountered. Further, I want to assign the value to a variable that I'll use later on for calculations in a sub I've written.

I have a pivot table that varies in width depending on how many months I choose to include. Please take a look at the picture in case my explanations are unclear :) (Can't embed images as my reputation is insufficient, but there's a link below) Ultimately, I want to count the number of months and store it as the value of a variable I call *numberofmonths*. I'm not very experienced with VBA and if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

I figured that one way to do this would be to define a range starting from (3,3), as this starting point is fixed, and ending at say (3,20) as I won't use more than 12 months at most, and then count the number of non-empty cells until the cell containing the text "Grand Total" is encountered. By the way, there is data in the cells next to the "Grand Total" column, and the values 17/01, 17/02,... are also found there, which is why I thought it would be better to stop once "Grand Total" is reached instead of using some sort of countif-approach. Is this possible at all? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzBpb.png

Comment: Please add  the code you have tried so far to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't written any code for this specific problem because I really don't know exactly how to address it. Couldn't find any questions similar enough either to get any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is possible with VBA. This Counts the Cells in Row 2, starting in Col B to the right until "Grand Total" is  reached. It returns the Number of Month as you wished.

```
Function CountMonth() As Integer
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastCol = sht.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To LastCol
    If sht.Cells(3, i).Value <> "Grand Total" Then
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Else 
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
CountMonth = Counter
End Function
```